Car Android screen wireless silences jack audio
I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus and an Android car screen that I bought recently. My car is a Mazda 3 sedan 2018 (display with no touchscreen). The head unit is connected to a DSP, amplifier, and 2-way 6,5" components. This is because I'm always looking for a better sound quality, therefore I reproduce music with my phone through DAC Fiio Q11 which sends the clean signal to my car head unit via a 4.4 balanced jack cable.
The problem comes with the Android car screen. When I connect it to my phone through BT, everything works fine except the music because the screen starts playing with its own internal speakers even when I disable the audio option in BT settings.
Also, I try to go to individual external player settings and set it to play music only on my phone, but the problem remains. So I was searching for this kind of problem and didn't find any solution. I have tried 4 Android apps and still nothing.
So I wonder, how can I lock the BT audio output in order to force the audio output of my phone?

The short answer is that you can't.  I have the same problem with a different scenario.  The design of the Bluetooth assumes that all audio is being directed to it, because that's what it is for.  You can see this in the sound settings when you are connected to Android Auto.  The other feature is that Android talks to only one device at a time, Bluetooth is Not a network. Unfortunately, other gadgets are trying to use Bluetooth for their own purposes and there are issues.
My situation is that I already have these

A smart watch
Hearing Aids

As soon as I plug in Android Auto, one of the other two fails.  Sometimes they keep doing a round robin.  The next version of Bluetooth has some promise.
My suggestion is to buy a cheap phone to play your audio.
